# Displaying NA values as transparent in geom_tile

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation

I am making a geom_tile plot.

Here is my data:

```
> cormatU.m
     X1 X2              value
1  PJan  3                 NA
2  PFeb  3                 NA
3  PMar  3                 NA
4  PApr  3 -0.161992302630029
5  PMay  3 -0.309114094976858
6   Jun  3 -0.336074090127203
7   Jul  3 -0.299397509057833
8   Aug  3 -0.238448926298331
9   Sep  3                 NA
10  Oct  3 -0.251843163432571
11  Nov  3  -0.27385055414082
12  Dec  3 -0.224421430174352
13  Jan  3   -0.3394060217504
14  Feb  3 -0.178520333980496
15  Mar  3 -0.245158851599677
16  Apr  3 -0.242129657088556
17  May  3 -0.172928147572245
18 PJan  4                 NA
19 PFeb  4 -0.225077539575345
20 PMar  4 -0.359309582752073
21 PApr  4                 NA
22 PMay  4 -0.189923565448835
23  Jun  4                 NA
24  Jul  4                 NA
25  Aug  4 -0.271119542271446
26  Sep  4                 NA
27  Oct  4 -0.204322223119054
28  Nov  4 -0.162222155770841
29  Dec  4 -0.289280496162877
30  Jan  4   -0.1760601312005
31  Feb  4                 NA
32  Mar  4                 NA
33  Apr  4 -0.261118372110555
34  May  4 -0.219750293141206
cormatU.m$X1<- factor(cormatU.m$X1, levels=c("PJan", "PFeb", "PMar", "PApr",     "PMay", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"))
cormatU.m$X2 <- factor(cormatU.m$X2, levels=c("3", "4")
```

I am having problem with the NAs present in my data frame. I have looked at other options where the na.value is set to transparent and have also tried setting my scale_fill as discrete, gradient and gradient2. However, every time I run the code it gives me an error

Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale.

Below is the code I've used in an attempt to produce the geom_tile plot. This is a plot that is displaying correlation coefficients. The NA values represent correlation coefficients that were non-significant. Any suggestions dealing with the NA values  are much appreciated. Thank you.

```
Ucor<- ggplot(cormatU.m, aes(X1,X2, fill=value))+
  geom_tile()+
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0), breaks=c("PJan", "PMar", "PMay", "Jul",     "Sep", "Nov", "Jan", "Mar", "May"))+ #only display those lables on x axis
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0))+  
  scale_fill_gradient(limits=c(-0.75,0.75), breaks=seq(-0.75,0.75,0.25),     low="green", high="red", na.value="transparent")+
```

Comment: It looks like `value` is not numeric. What does `str(cormatU.m$value)` tell you.

Comment: Do `cormatU.m <- transform(cormatU.m, value=as.numeric(value))` then try your code again.

Comment: @AlexA. I still get the same error.....

Comment: @Roland It tells me that its a factor which is what I set it as in the above lines of code. It is just really not liking the NA values...

Comment: @AlexA. I misinterpreted your suggestion.. yup, converting to a numeric did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: @Roland. Converting to numeric did the trick! Thanks for your hint!

Comment: Glad to hear it. I'll post it as an answer so the resolution is obvious for others who stumble upon this page.

Comment: If the values are not numeric you should find out the reason for that. You should preferably fix it during data import.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `value` in `cormatU.m` is not numeric. To remedy this, you can do:

```
cormatU.m <- transform(cormatU.m, value=as.numeric(as.character(value)))
```

Why `as.character()`? Notice that if you do `as.numeric()` without it, the values will be incorrect. This is because of how R deals with factor variables. Converting to character first and then to numeric will ensure that the values are read exactly how they appear in your data frame.